# Hiding Action name from URL

Tags: c#

My url is this,

> localhost:45678/Blogs/Index

I need it like this format

> localhost:45678/Blogs

i write below code in route file but,

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Blog",
            url: "{Blog}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "forblogcontent",
            url: "Blog/{slug}/{id}", 
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Blog",
                action = "DisplayContent",
                slug = UrlParameter.Optional
            }   
            );

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "AddContent", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

When i click on an link button it still shows

> localhost:45678/Blogs/Index

My link button code is

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Blog")">Blogs</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

How to correct this?

Comment: show your full `Routeconfig.cs` ?

Comment: please add code in your post. the code in comment is unreadable

Comment: Take a look at this answer. I think this is what your are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9495306/4935997

Comment: @Ajo, does your problem solved?

Comment: yes @er-sho , i just add these comments in route  ` routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Blog",
                url: "Blog",
                defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" }
            );  `